# Fourier transform: How long should the observed period be with respect to the frequencies that I expect to observe?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

For an application, I need to obtain the Fourier transform of an observed period of time from an electroencephalogram (actually a STFT, but that isn't too relevant). However, I worry that the observed periods might sometimes be too short with respect to the wave lengths that I expect to observe. My intuition tells me that the observed period should be well above a particular wave length in order for the Fourier transform to accurately capture its presence.

Is my intuition correct? How long should the observed period be with respect to a wave length to estimate its presence?

Answer (score 1):

We should use appropriately matching units; the observed period needs to be significantly longer than the reciprocal of the frequency - equivalently, wavelength divided by speed.

For more precision, there's the [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle) for the Fourier transform; the product of the time uncertainty of a signal and the frequency uncertainty is at least a constant. If you cut things off with a too-short signal, you'll spread out the observed frequencies to a broader range than they should be.

Checking a reference - EEG data is mostly concentrated in the $10$ Hz range, and variations of less than $1$ Hz in frequency are a big deal. To capture that, you'll need significantly more than a second of data.

Comment: Thanks! When you say "significantly more than a second of data", how much is significant? Do you know about some reasonable way of deciding how long I need?